# source.yml file that includes multiple catalogs and schemas in DBT

Tags: dbt

I am using DBT and Trino to create different Iceberg materialization.

In my **staging** folder, I am importing tables from multiple catalogs and different schemas, thus I configure my models like that:

```
{{ config(
    database="<myTrinoCatlog>",
    schema="<myCatlogSchema>"
) }}
```

When I try to configure the **sources.yml** file to set my source tables like this:

```
version: 2

sources:
  - name: schema
  tables:
    - name : table1
    - name : table2
```

I couldn't find a way to switch between catalogs, DBT always refers to the schema and catalog given in the profiles.yml file.
How can I include tables from different catalogs and schemas?